# Adding N elements of array in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I have stored 10 integers into an array and I have to add N integers from that array. N is the index upto which I have to do the addition and N is entered by the user. I am getting an error while executing following code. The sum is always zero

```
.data

promptInts: .asciiz "Enter 10 integers: \n"                # Prompt User to enter 10 integers
promptIndex: .asciiz "Enter an Index: " 
output_neg: .asciiz "\nThe sum is negative"
output_pos: .asciiz "\nThe sum is non-negative"          # Prompt user to enter an Index 
.align 2
array: .space 40                                          # declaring an array of size 40

.text

main:
    la $t0, array                        # t0 = Load the address of our array 
    li $t1, 0                           # t1 = Number of elements in the array
    li $t2, 10                          # t2 = upper limit of the array i.e. 10 elements

    la $a0, promptInts                   # Get the address of the string ready for the syscall
    li $v0, 4                           # syscall code for print string
    syscall

storenumbers:
    li $v0, 5                           # Syscall code for read integer
    syscall
    sw $v0, ($t0)                       # store the input integer into the array
    addi $t1, $t1, 1                    # add 1 to the number of elements
    addi $t0, $t0, 4                    # move to the next address in the array
    bne $t1, $t2, storenumbers          # keep adding numbers till we have 10 numbers

    # Once we have our 10 numbers, ask user to input an Index from 1-10
    la $a0, promptIndex                 # Get the address of the string ready for the syscall
    li $v0, 4                           # syscall code for print string
    syscall
    li $v0, 5                           # Syscall code for read integer
    syscall
    move $t3, $v0                       # t3 = user input Index (copy the input index to $t3)

    li $t4, 0                           # t4 = counter for index (loop counter)
    li $t5, 0                           # t5 = sum of the elements (initialized to 0)
addnumbers:
    lw $t6, ($t0)                       # t6 = load one element from the array ( array[i] )
    addi $t4, $t4, 1                    # increment the counter for index
    addi $t0, $t0, 4                    # get the next address in the array
    add $t5, $t6, $t6                   # update the sum
    bne $t3, $t4, addnumbers            # keep adding numbers till we reach the desired index
    
    
    bgtz $t5, positive_sum              # if the sum >= 0 go to positive_sum, else run the next line
    la $a0, output_neg                 # Get the address of the string ready for the syscall
    li $v0, 4                           # syscall code for print string
    syscall

    j done

positive_sum:
    la $a0, output_pos                 # Get the address of the string ready for the syscall
    li $v0, 4                           # syscall code for print string
    syscall 

done:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

I think its because either my elements are not being loaded in $t6 or they are not being added properly in $t5. Please help me with this, any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried debugging it: using single step to observe the behavior of each instruction?  If just one instruction is incorrect the program won't work.  Hint: try it on the smallest possible input, which would be an array of 1 element.

Comment: I actually tried. Its the sum that is not being calculated properly. I think I may have used wrong conditions but I cant seem to get it right. Thats why I need some help :)

Comment: `add $t5, $t6, $t6` is wrong. You want `add $t5, $t5, $t6`

Comment: Fixed that still no luck :/

Comment: Also you need to reload `$t0` because your `storenumbers` loop changes it.

Comment: Debugging is a critical skill for programming, and absolutely essential for assembly language.  You have to single step each line and observe whether it has the proper and intended effect.  One of those effects is control flow, which is also checked and verified by single stepping.  Do not guess at what is happening -- there's no magic, so observe it instead.   You will find either that one instruction does not do what you're expecting in computation, or that one instruction will not change the flow control the way you are expecting.  Test on small input like input size of 1.

Comment: If "the sum that is not being calculated properly." that will boil down to one instruction that isn't doing its job the way you expect.  Up your debugging skills.  Single step, looking at registers, verifying computations and control flow on every instruction.

Comment: Thank you everyonefor their help. Debugged the program successfully.